# api-maps.yandex.ru и "Invalid API key"

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Почему запрос к api с определённого домена может отдавать ошибку 403?

```
$ curl -LIk 'https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU' -H 'Referer: http://promenade-expo.bi-group.org/' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36' --compressed

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 09 Jan 2019 09:22:24 GMT
Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 15
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=120
Vary: Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=json.txt
X-qloud-router: iva6-1d59cc6b9427.qloud-c.yandex.net

$ curl -LIk 'https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU' -H 'Referer: http://armankala.bi-group.org/' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36' --compressed
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 09 Jan 2019 09:22:36 GMT
Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=120
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=json.txt
X-LIGHTTPD-LOCALE: ru_RU
Timing-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-qloud-router: sas2-10c1768f2c0f.qloud-c.yandex.net

$ curl 'https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU' -H 'Referer: http://promenade-expo.bi-group.org/' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36' --compressed

Invalid API key
```

Используется один код на пачке поддоменов, ошибка генерируется только на одном

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async
                src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3Aa42f4a070150a9b7af9ae6bb59bb3857551025aa15256e6cbe1dfc4a932d9736&amp;width=100%25&amp;height=400&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;sourceType=constructor&amp;scroll=true"></script>
```

Comment: ключ получен и использован : `<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=<ваш API-ключ>&lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript">` - результат тот же

Comment: По вопросам доступа к API стоит писать в техподдержку с указанием домена и ip адреса. 403 это ошибка не вашего кода, а доступа. Может быть ключ неправильный (от другого API) или вы превысили лимит или ещё что-то не так, что может сказать только техподдержка.

Answer (score 1):

Действительно была блокировка со стороны Yandex, вопрос закрыт

> Ваш домен был заблокирован нашей автоматикой, так как она сочла его
>   закрытой системой.